determine slope, rsq, and p_value as columns from pandas dataframe
I have:
dd = {'d_2023-09': {0: 23.0, 1: 14.0, 2: 15.0, 3: 10.0}, 'd_2023-10': {0: 20.0, 1: 8.0, 2: 7.0, 3: 12.0}, 'd_2023-11': {0: 14.0, 1: 9.0, 2: 11.0, 3: 11.0}, 'd_2023-12': {0: 19.0, 1: 17.0, 2: 13.0, 3: 7.0}, 'd_2024-01': {0: 18.0,
1: 11.0, 2: 19.0, 3: 10.0}, 'd_2024-02': {0: 13.0, 1: 4.0, 2: 6.0, 3: 13.0}, 'd_2024-03': {0: 21.0, 1: 10.0, 2: 11.0, 3: 6.0}}
df = pd.DataFrame(dd)

I would like to create 3 new columns, each representing the slope,rsq,and pvalue of the last 6 columns vs [1,2,3,4,5,6]
I tried:
df['slope']= np.polyfit(df[[i for i in dd.columns][-6:]],[1,2,3,4,5,6],1)[0]

to no avail.
Are there any suggestions how to proceed?

this one liner works
dd[['slope','intercept','r','p','se']]=dd[[i for i in dd.columns if 'd_' in i][-6:]].apply(lambda x: linregress(range(1,len(x)+1), x.values), axis = 1).apply(pd.Series)

